# How to classify Iris flowers

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I want to classify Iris flowers from the famous Iris data set using MLP. I know that I the number of neurons in output layer should be  the same number of classes but can I  use one neuron in output layer which output is the value (0 or 1 or -1) to refer to the three types ?

```
trin= [4.7 3.2 1.6 0.2;
       4.8 3.1 1.6 0.2;
       5.4 3.4 1.5 0.4;
       5.2 4.1 1.5 0.1;
       5.5 4.2 1.4 0.2;
      5.7 2.6 3.5 1;
      5.5 2.4 3.8 1.1;
      5.5 2.4 3.7 1;
      5.8 2.7 3.9 1.2;
      6 2.7 5.1 1.6;
      6.7 3.3 5.7 2.1;
      7.2 3.2 6 1.8;
      6.2 2.8 4.8 1.8;
      6.1 3 4.9 1.8;
      6.4 2.8 5.6 2.1
      ];
trout=[-1;-1;-1;-1;-1;
   0;0;0;0;0;
   1;1;1;1;1];
inp=size(trin,2);
 out=size(trout,2);
 hidden=2;


x=[-0.8000,-1.520,-0.9400,-3.040,3.800,2,-2,3.790,-1,0,4.600,4.400,0];
iw = reshape(x(1:hidden*inp),hidden,inp);
b1 = reshape(x(hidden*inp+1:hidden*inp+hidden),hidden,1);
lw = reshape(x(hidden*inp+hidden+1:hidden*inp+hidden+hidden*out),out,hidden);
b2 = reshape(x(hidden*inp+hidden+hidden*out+1:hidden*inp+hidden+hidden*out+out),out,1);

y =       tanh(tanh(trin*iw'+repmat(b1',size(trin,1),1))*lw'+repmat(b2',size(trin,1),1));
 e = gsubtract(trout,y);

is this classification or it is considered as regression
```

Comment: this question is better suited here : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ as stack overflow website is more  Q&A programing related

Comment: Please provide some code you tried, are you using some library or doing it from scratch?

Comment: my problem is classification is this acceptable ????

Comment: if you have problem with your code, you can post it here, but if your problem is the concept or method, you should post on data science site